# Building an array from a series of CheckBox controls

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, checkbox

I have a small problem regarding arrays.

This is the code:

```
char[] select = new char[] { '+', '-', '/', '%' };
var rand = new Random();
char num = select[rand.Next(5)];
```

I have five `CheckBox` controls. If my control named `checkboxadd` is checked, I want the array to have the value of `{ + }`. And if my controls named `checkboxadd` and `checkboxsubtract` are checked, I want the value of the array to change to `{ +, - }`. And so on.

Is this possible?

**More:** I am creating a Windows Forms application. The application is an arithmetic learning system which offers a set of operations which are selected via `CheckBox` controls. I think my approach is wrong...can anyone help?

Comment: `select` is a reserved keyword. You should escape it using `@select` or use a different name for the variable.

Comment: Your code sample and your question don't make sense together. Why are you selecting a random element in your array, and what does that have to do with checkboxes?

Comment: Also, what version of .NET are you using? There are easier ways to do this on newer versions, if I understand your question correctly, which I'm not 100% sure I do.

Answer (score 2):

You add your checkboxes in the Designer (so they are created in the InitializeComponent() call). After that you initialize a helper Array that allows elegant coding in the CheckedChanged event handler. So you react on every change in a checked state:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private CheckBox[] checkboxes;
    private char[] operators;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        checkboxes = new[] { checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3, checkBox4, checkBox5 };
        checkBox1.Tag = '+';
        checkBox2.Tag = '-';
        checkBox3.Tag = '*';
        checkBox4.Tag = '/';
        checkBox5.Tag = '%';
        foreach (var cb in checkboxes) {
            cb.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
        }
    }

    private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        operators = checkboxes.Where(cb => cb.Checked)
            .Select(cb => cb.Tag)
            .Cast<char>()
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: The methods `Where`, `Select`, `Cast` and `ToArray` are defined in the [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class which is the basis for [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx).